# jasper report to pdf conversion error using jsp. It shows failed to load pdf

Tags: spring-mvc, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

[this is my project viewer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRJeY.png)

**Search.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>

<body>

   <h3>Search the id which you want</h3>

   <form method="POST" action="filereport.jsp">

       <p>Give the searching ID</p>

       <input type="text" name="employid"/><br>

       <input type="submit" value="show"/>

   </form>

 </body>

</html>
```

**filereport.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>

<%@ page  import="java.io.*"%> 

<%@ page  import="java.sql.Connection"%> 

<%@ page  import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>

<%@ page  import="java.util.HashMap"%>

<%@ page  import="java.util.Map"%>

<%@ page  import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@page import="Class.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

   <head>

       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

       <title>JSP Page</title>

   </head>

   <body>

       <h2>your searching result is :</h2>

       <%

          Connection conn=null;

          try{

              //connection to mysql database

           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

           conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/product?user=root&password=mysql123");

         ////Loading Jasper Report File from Local file system

           String jrxmlFile = session.getServletContext().getRealPath(request.getContextPath())+"/Reports/reportgenerate.jasper";

           InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(jrxmlFile));

           Map parameters = new HashMap();

           int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("employid"));

           parameters.put("employeeid", id);

           //generating the report
           JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input);

           JasperPrint jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters,conn);

           //byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parameters, conn.getconnection());

           //exporting the report as pdf
//          
           ////Exporting the report as a PDF 

           JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response.getOutputStream());

          }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

              e.printStackTrace();

          }catch(JRException e){

              e.printStackTrace();

          }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

              e.printStackTrace();

          }catch(SQLException e){

              e.printStackTrace();

          }finally{

              if(conn!=null){

                  conn.close();
              }
          }

       %>

   </body>

</html>
```

he problem is when i run the file a blank pdf view opens and shows an error "Failed to load pdf document". Can anybody help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you still have issues?

Comment: @PetterFriberg -  Hey, Thanks but I have tried your solution and still have issues.Don't understand whats left!

Comment: Same issues as before or others?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues:

1. You should `flush` and `close` `response.getOutputStream()`

Example

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response.getOutputStream());
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();
```

Consider to use `try` `catch` statements for `close()`, and also to add correct headers for your response.

2. If the report datasource is empty and you do not have attribute `whenNoDataType` on your `jasperReport` tag, it will generate an empty pdf, that may cause troubles. You can change this behaviour setting the `whenNoDataType="BlankPage"` or whatever you see most fitted. see [WhenNoDataTypeEnum API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/WhenNoDataTypeEnum.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem could be from your browser (Chrome) settings. You should go to your settings in your Chrome browser, then go to privacy, then go to the site settings, then scroll down to PDF documents, and remove the selection "Open from Chrome" and select "Download PDFs"

Maybe another issue could be that you didn't `flush` and `close` your `outputStream` after using it; i.e.,

```
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```